# How do I replace the QUEUES content in twilio flex AgentDesktop?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I want to either replace the content element within the QUEUES element, or remove it and add a custom tab. Is this possible?

[image]

I was able to remove all the tab content using

```
flex.WorkerDirectory.Content.replace(<div key="tabs">CustomTabs</div>);
```

However, I want to keep the 'transfer' header so I can close that panel

Answer (score 0):

This is a start

```
    flex.WorkerDirectory.Content.remove("tabs");
flex.WorkerDirectory.Content.add(<div class="Twilio-Tabs Twilio Twilio-WorkerDirectoryTabs css-1vzbs6y" key="worker-directory">
  <div class="Twilio-Tabs-Labels css-1a43y29">
    <div class="Twilio-TabHeader css-y47si7">
      <button class="css-1i3d2ep"><span class="Twilio">QUEUES</span></button>
      <div class="Twilio-TabHeader-StateIndicator-Inactive css-1qqd035"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button">SomeQueueName1</button>
</div>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You should target `Flex.WorkerDirectory.Tabs`, instead of `Flex.WorkerDirectory`. That way you have access directly to the Tabs content. First remove the queues tab:

```
 Flex.WorkerDirectory.Tabs.Content.remove("queues");
```

You can then add a new tab like this:

```
Flex.WorkerDirectory.Tabs.Content.add(
   <Flex.Tab
         key="new-tab
         label="New Tab"
    >
         <div>New tab content here</div>
   </Flex.Tab>
);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.